# require is not defined using phantomjs in meteor 1.0

Tags: meteor, phantomjs

Using phantomjs with Meteor 1.0. In the server/lib/phantomjs.js file, I had the lines of codes:

```
var args = require('system').args,
    openPage = require('./openPage');
```

The app crashes when starting the server saying require is not defined. What's the right way to use phantomjs in meteor?

Comment: How do you use it from the server? Do you use child_process/spawn to run the script? PhantomJS doesn't have the same runtime as node and is **not** a node module.

Comment: yes, i used child_process.spawn to run the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phantom script should be put in the private directory instead of the server directory. Files in the private directory are considered as server side assets.

> Assets are not processed as source files and are copied directly into your application's bundle.